# Get reference of object inside of div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reference an object inside of a div, using **plain** JavaScript:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="search">
        <input type="text" id="query" />
        <button onclick="test()">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function test() {
        try {
            var main = document.getElementById("main");
            var search = main.getElementById("search");
            alert(search);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: main.getElementById is not a function(…)

Referencing `main` works, but not what's inside of `main`.

I also set up [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch2xutym/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an element inside of other use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector('#main #search')
```

As `ID` is unique, you can directly use

```
document.getElementById('search')
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is there is no method called `getElemetnById()` attached to the `Element` object.

Since ID of an element must be unique there is need to do that, just use `document.getElementById()`.

But if you want to make sure the said element is a descendant of anotehr element you can use `document.querSelector('#main #search')`

Answer (score 1):

DOM Elements don't have `getElementById` method. Only `document` object have this method. 
Id attribute specifies a **unique** id for the element. 
It means only one element can have `id="search"`. So you can use `document.getElementById("search");`